# How to get parsed Date from Sqlite3 databse with Java?

Tags: java, jsp, sqlite

I am getting data from sqlite3 DB, by creating a model for my method with POJO. While retrieving data in a arraylist I am getting parse error for date. The date is defined as timestamp in the sqlite3 DB and while compiling it is throwing : **Unparseable date: "2015-05-21 12:41:56" error**. And while compiling query it is throwing : **Error parsing time stamp** I am using getDate() to retrieve date from the table.

```
public List<EnergyMeter> getAllData() {
    List<EnergyMeter> meters = new ArrayList<EnergyMeter>();
    try {
        LOGGER.info("############### FetchData.getAllData() start");
        Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ENERGY_METER");
        LOGGER.info("############### FetchData.getAllData() meters:"+rs.getDate("CREATION_TIME"));
        while (rs.next()) {
            EnergyMeter energyMeter = new EnergyMeter();
            energyMeter.setDEVICE_IP(rs.getString("IP"));
            energyMeter.setCREATION_TIME(rs.getDate("CREATION_TIME"));
            energyMeter.setDESCRIPTION(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
            energyMeter.setDEVICE_NAME(rs.getString("DEVICE_NAME"));
            energyMeter.setEMAIL_ID(rs.getString("EMAIL_ID"));
            energyMeter.setFDU_NAME(rs.getString("FDU_NAME"));
            energyMeter.setICBS(rs.getString("ICBS"));
            energyMeter.setLOCATION(rs.getString("LOCATION"));
            energyMeter.setMAC_ADDRESS(rs.getString("MAC_ADDRESS"));
            energyMeter.setMASTER_ID(rs.getString("MASTER_ID"));
            energyMeter.setPARAMETER(rs.getString("PARAMETER"));
            energyMeter.setPORT(rs.getString("PORT"));
            energyMeter.setPRODUCT_NAME(rs.getString("PRODUCT_NAME"));
            energyMeter.setSMTP(rs.getString("SMTP"));
            energyMeter.setSNMP(rs.getString("SNMP"));
            meters.add(energyMeter);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LOGGER.info("############### FetchData.getAllData() end");
    return meters;
}
```

I defined date as : **private Date CREATION_TIME;** in POJO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite3 doesn't provide a date type.

You need to get it as a String and parse it in Java.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(rs.getString("CREATION_TIME")); //Throws exception
```

See: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: With the proper dialect it is possible to get dates from SQLite database and Hibernate, manual parsing is not needed. See https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/hibernate4-sqlite-dialect

Comment: @peceps nice one, this wasn't available at the time. You should post an answer :)